# Are there any books similar to Universe?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, resource-recommendations, standard-model

I enjoy to read Universe by Roger A. Freedman and William J. Kaufmann. I love this book because it contains lots of images and illustrations about the contents so i do not get bored with all the details. That's what i loved about the Universe. And i am not having any problem with the math in the book so far.

Are there any books similar to this but about Standard Model, Particle Physics or Quantum Field Theory.

(The math can be harder than Universe, it is okay.)
[image: Universe][image: Universe][image: Universe]

Comment: No, it is not duplicate. The other question is simply asking about any book that easy to understand about the concepts. What i want to learn is if there are any books similar to the book that i described.